# I can't run Java on Terminal?

Tags: java, windows-terminal

So I have been trying to run some of my school assignments, which are written in Java.

[image: 1]

This is the only screenshot I can get, because every time I try to run it, the Java Console Launcher pops up and ask for permission, then no matter what I click, the program does not run. Although I can run it on VS Code for some reason, so I don't know what is the problem here.

I tried reinstalling Java with the aid of my instructor, but the problem persists.

Comment: I think that you need to define your PATH VARIABLE, then the keyword Java would be recognizable by your machine, setting PATH / ENVIROMENT VARIABLES have different steps based on your OS

Answer (score 1):

When you type a command in the terminal it looks for the application using the operating systems PATH variable. The java installer (and most other programs for that matter) doesn't modify that variable, so you have to add it manually.

Find out where your java installation is, usually somewhere like C:\Program Files\Java\jdkXXX\bin

You can set the variable temporarily in your terminal like so:

`set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdkXXX\bin`

and then verify if it works by typing `java -version`

If that all works, then you can modify your Windows PATH variable. There are lots of guides online for how to do that depending on your version of windows. Just make sure you append the jdk forlder instead of replacing the whole thing.